# How to free double pointers in structs c?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, free

I tried to implement Queue.In my deleteq function I want to free only the pointer to another struct(elemet of queue) and return pointer to value of the deleted element,but free function causes an error:Segmentation fault.

```
struct Node{
   void* val;
   struct Node* next;
};

typedef struct Queue{
    struct Node* head;
    struct Node* tail;
}Queue;

Queue nw_queue(void* val){
    struct Node *node_ptr = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    node_ptr->val = val;
    node_ptr->next = NULL;
    Queue q;
    q.head = node_ptr;
    q.tail = node_ptr;
    return q;
}



void add(Queue *q, void* val){
    struct Node *node_ptr = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    node_ptr->val = val;
    node_ptr->next = NULL;
    if (empty(*q)){
        *q = nw_queue(val);
        return ;
    }
    q->tail->next = node_ptr;
    q->tail = node_ptr;
}

void* deleteq(Queue* q_ptr){
    if (empty(*q_ptr)){
        puts("Error deleteq:Empty queue");
        return NULL;
    }
    struct Node* cur_head = q_ptr->head;
    q_ptr->head = q_ptr->head->next;
    struct Node** toFree = &(cur_head->next);
    free(toFree); //Error
    return cur_head->val;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    Queue q = nw_queue(&a);
    add(&q, &a);
    deleteq(&q);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You appear to be having a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), you can't use a pointer after `free()`ing it.

Comment: regarding: `struct Node *node_ptr = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));`  When calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` 1) the returned value has type `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  if not successful, call `perror( "malloc failed" );` then cleanup then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: where is the function: `empty()`?

Comment: the posted code does not compile!.  Amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, but the following is certainly wrong

```
struct Node** toFree = &(cur_head->next);
free(toFree); //Error
```

you are freeing a *stack* address there, not a pointer that was returned by `malloc()`/`calloc()`/`realloc()`, anything else that you pass to `free()` is undefined behavior.

So the fix is, only pass to `free()` anything that you `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()` i.e. *dynamically allocated memory*.

Why am I so sure that the code above is wrong? Becase `&` will give you the address of something, and that's a pointer of course but not one returned by `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()` which are the only ones allowed to be `free()`ed.

Comment: But I thought, that, if I malloced space for struct, when I created the element in add or nw_queue, I malloced space for the pointers in struct as well. Is it correct? @Iharob Al Asimi

Comment: Yes, you should `malloc()` any pointer that is supposed to point to dynamically generated, you then put data in the address that the pointer stores, and then `free()` when you no longer need to access the pointer. I appears that what you really need is to study pointers a little more.

Comment: It is not a stack address; it is the address of a variable within (but not at the beginning of) a heap-allocated object. `&cur_head` would be a stack address; `cur_head->next` is a member of the object that `cur_head` points to, and `&(cur_head->next)` is the address of the member within that object. It is the wrong thing to free, but it is not a stack address.

Comment: I don't know why, but my code works if I swap declarations in struct Node definiton.

Comment: Read about undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. only creates a single linked list rather than a double linked list.  It is up to the OP to add the 'prev' links
2. for convenience. used different function names
3. eliminated the creation of the queue function
4. eliminated treating the queue head radically different from the other queue nodes
5. properly checks for error indications from C library functions
6. for flexibility, separates the struct definition from the typedef for the struct
7. does not create a circular queue

The following code should point the OP in the right direction, without writing all the code for them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct Queue
{
    void   *data;
    struct Queue* next;
    struct Queue* prev;
};
typedef struct Queue Queue;


// prototypes
void addq( Queue **q, void* val );
void delq( Queue **q );


int main( void )
{
    int a = 5;
    Queue *q = NULL;

    addq( &q, (void*)&a);
    delq( &q);

    return 0;
}


void addq( Queue **q, void* val )
{
    struct Queue *node_ptr = malloc(sizeof(*node_ptr ));
    if( !node_ptr )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    node_ptr->data = val;
    node_ptr->next = NULL;

    if (!*q )
    {
        *q = node_ptr;
        return ;
    }

    Queue *current;
    for( current = *q; current->next; current = current->next );

    current->next = node_ptr;
}


void delq( Queue **q )
{
    if( !*q )
    {
        puts("Error deleteq:Empty queue");
    }

    struct Queue  *cur_head = *q;
    *q = (*q)->next;

    free( cur_head );
}
```